# Hodge-Tate decomposition for tori

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, galois-representations

I am reading the article "On the Order of the Reduction of a Point on an Abelian Variety", R.Pink ([here](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Epink/ftp/ReductionOfAPoint.20031127.pdf) is a link to the article).

I am stuck on the proof of Proposition 1.4. Here, the author uses the Hodge-Tate decomposition but I do not understand which decomposition he used (he cited a letter of Serre, but I can not find it anywhere). After searching, the Hodge-Tate decomposition seems to involve cohomology of abelian varieties, while here it seems that the decomposition is used for tori. I don't see how the author uses the decomposition in this situation.

Can someone give me a hint or a reference to the decomposition in the proof?